# ASP.Net array loses structure with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a ASP.Net MVC Razor application.
in my controller, I load two dictionaries with data and place them in a ViewModel as follows:

```
    public Dictionary<String, List<String>> EngineerSchedule { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, List<String>> WeeklySchedule { get; set; }
```

when in the view, I traverse the dictionaries to retrieve the List objects at every Key, I then change this String List into an Array and send them to a JavaScript function.

In my Js function, I would like to assign the above array to JS variables, when doing so, the JS variables become an array where the index holds the entire array from the function call.
Also, the params become an array of Chars

Any advice to why this happens will be greatly appreciated!

Code in View:

```
@foreach(var week in Model.WeeklySchedule)
{
    var key = week.Key;
    var values = week.Value.ToArray();

    string[] eng = { };

    foreach (var item in Model.EngineerSchedule)
    {
        if (item.Key == key)
        {
            eng = item.Value.ToArray();
        }
    }

    @: gatherTimes('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(key))', '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(values))', '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(eng))'); 
    //In here, both values and engs are Array of the correct type and length
}

function gatherTimes(weekKey, values, engs)
{
    var week =[];
    var eng = [];

    week[week.length] = values;
    eng[eng.length] = engs;

    for(var i = 0; i < engs.length; i++)
    {
        alert(engs[i]); //Outputs single chars, rather then the string values
        alert(eng[i]); //Outputs an array with the length of all the chars from engs, but this array only has one value, which is the entire array from Engs
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to inject server side information into the JavaScript portion of your application is "stringifying" the .Net object and calling JSON.Parse on the client side.

If you have the Json.NET nuget package from Newtonsoft you can use the static method `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`
to turn almost any C# data structure into a JSON string.

After you place that string of JSON into your view using the templating feature of the Razor view engine, you can store it to a variable like so:

```
var engineerString = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.EngineerSchedule);
var dictionary = JSON.parse(engineerString);
```

Comment: mhm alright, seems like a viable solution, ill look into the lib and try it out.

Comment: Truth be told, C# objects and JavaScript objects don't play nicely together. My suggestion for you would be to make an AJAX request back to the server and retrieve your dictionaries that way. In general, the Razor view engine is great for templating HTML but it falls short when it's time to template data to be used in your JavaScript code.

Comment: I strongly agree with your statement, as I am now experiencing that first hand. I shall also look into making an AJAX request. I guess, I should prepare the array in the controller and use a AJAX request to retrieve said array?

Comment: Yeah, so I'd have a controller method, lets call it 

`public ActionResult GetEngineerSchedule()`

This will at the end `return Json(blah);`

If you need additional help feel free to edit your question at the top.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are actually giving your javascript function strings as arguments since they are wrapped in quotes. Maybe there lies the confusion?